# AngularJS Bootstrap radio button group

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to set up a radio button group using the tutorial from here:

https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

So in my view I created this:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="btn-group">
        <label class="btn btn-primary" ng-model="controller.selectedLines[0].forDelivery">For delivery</label>
        <label class="btn btn-primary" ng-model="!controller.selectedLines[0].forDelivery">For collection</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

My problem is I can't get the button to be selected.
In their example, they had different booleans for each button, but mine has to share the boolean, so if the boolean value is **true** then the button "For delivery" should be active, if the value is **false** then the "For collection" should be active.

I tried doing it like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
        <label class="btn btn-default" ng-class="active: controller.selectedLines[0].forDelivery === true">
            <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" ng-model="controller.selectedLines[0].forDelivery" ng-value="true" ng-change="deliveryController.requestDeliveryDate(controller.order, controller.selectedLines)"> For delivery
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-default" ng-class="active: controller.selectedLines[0].forDelivery === false">
            <input type="radio" name="optionsRadios" ng-model="controller.selectedLines[0].forDelivery" ng-value="false" ng-change="deliveryController.requestDeliveryDate(controller.order, controller.selectedLines)"> For collection
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

but that had the same issue.
Does anyone know how I can get it to select the button based on my value?

Comment: Can you create plunker?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Referring to the example given in https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

```
<div class="btn-group">
    <label class="btn btn-primary" ng-model="radioModel" btn-radio="'Left'">Left</label>
    <label class="btn btn-primary" ng-model="radioModel" btn-radio="'Middle'">Middle</label>
    <label class="btn btn-primary" ng-model="radioModel" btn-radio="'Right'">Right</label>
</div>
```

When `radioModel='Left'` the left button is selected.

As for your scenario, some options are missing. Here is the working code

```
<div class="btn-group">
    <label class="btn btn-primary" ng-model="mode" btn-radio="'Delivery'">For delivery</label>
    <label class="btn btn-primary" ng-model="mode" btn-radio="'Collection'">For collection</label>
</div>
```

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/HsNwvigsZD3z7fIrIENG)

Comment: Any chance to make this working with the newest ui-bootstrap-tpls?

Comment: The selected button id is deselected when clicking away from the control. Any simple way to retain the selection?

Comment: btn-radio should now be uib-btn-radio re: http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#%2Fbuttons